# How to fix repeating data on tableview cell form?

Tags: swift, uitableview, tableview

Been searching for this answer for about a month and can't find a solution.

**How do you fix repeating cell data so that it is not duplicated when you scroll? The only field I entered data into is "3731 Black Cherry Greek" When I scroll it duplicates the cases and units fields. "3665 Coconut NOUNOS" & "1243 Rasp Lemonade SS" should still be blank. I have spent hours trying to find the solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.**

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bf2Bd.jpg)

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int { return 1 }
        
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int { return inventoryArray.count }
    
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! cell

cell.unitField.tag = (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row
cell.unitField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(Inventory.unitCell(_:)), for: UIControl.Event.editingDidEnd)
                    
return cell as cell
  
}



@IBAction func unitCell(_ sender: UIButton) {

let tag = sender.tag

let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath.init(row: tag, section: 0)) as! InventoryCell

var intUnit = Int(cell.unitField.text!)!

cell.count.text = String (intUnit) 

}}
```

Comment: Are you aware that cells are reused by the tableview?

Comment: Cells are reused. Don't modify contents of the cell directly. Modify the data model and reload the row. And replace `(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row` with `indexPath.row`, the bridge cast is pointless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's important to remember that you are literally reusing the cells. If you modify one of them and scroll down, that same cell will appear again, which is what you're experiencing.

In order to solve this, you need to define exactly what a cell should look like each time it reappears. If there's data, add it to the label. Otherwise, *reset the label to blank.*

```
cell.unitField.tag = (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row
cell.unitField.text = "" // empty the textField
cell.unitField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(Inventory.unitCell(_:)), for: UIControl.Event.editingDidEnd)
```

If you don't manually reset it, it will keep the information you gave it last time.

Comment: It works but would like to keep the data in the unit field that are already entered. Any way to do this?

Comment: Great! As vadian commented above, you want the UI to be a reflection of your data. Rather than basing your cell off of the textField, base it off of your model. `let inventoryItem = inventoryArray[indexPath.row]` and `cell.unitField.text = inventoryItem.whatever`. Then it's just a matter of modifying that same inventory item inside your `func unitCell(_:)`

Comment: Im learning here. Whats an example of .whatever? What would I put there? Thanks for your help

Comment: Is `[inventoryArray]` made of a custom class or struct that you defined? If so, I assume it has some property on it that you're trying to gather in these textFields. Like `.address` or `.name`. When you go to display these textFields, you should make the `unitField.text` equal to whatever property it is that you're wanting to display. If that property hasn't been defined by the user yet, then the field should simply remain blank. Once the user inputs a value, you should do the reverse and save that input as a property on the corresponding "inventoryItem".